# Why Output does not work in web component?

Tags: angular, web-component

I have a custom element in Angular. I emit a value ffter initialize a component.

```
  @Output() onselected = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onselected.emit(this.selected);
  }
```

Then in native JS I catch it:

```
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
menu.addEventListener("onselected", (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Template is:

```
<menu id="menu"></menu>
```

But I did not get the console value.

Why?

Comment: No idea why this is getting downvotes. Your code looks good and I would expect this to work. Maybe you’re attaching your listener after the event already fired?

Comment: How it can be? Could you explain I will lcheck. How I can fit ?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code/html where you actually are using the element? Instead of firing the emit in ngOnInit, try a button in the element that triggers the emit and check if that works

Comment: It works by button, but I need to emit value instantly after web component is loaded

Comment: So.. okay. Make sure you setup your listener before the angular scripts in the HTML?

Comment: yes, first I get custom element by id, then I try listen it

Comment: ``addEventListener("onselected"`` will only listen when the emitted EventName is ``"onselected"``

Comment: Yes, so I made this `setTimeout(() => { this.onselected.emit(value)}, 1000)` It works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in Angular you need to listen to the event you emitted. Angular doesn't really want you to use Vanilla JS to access the DOM.

So, in your child component, you can emit an event like you did above.

```js
  @Output() onselected = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.onselected.emit(this.selected);
  }
```

And in your parent component, you will bind to that event in the HTML template.

```html
<app-child-component (onselected)="handleEventInParent($event)"></app-child-component>
```

In your parent `component.ts` file, your function would be like so

```ts
handleEventInParent(arg) {
//do something in here with the args passed from your event emitter
}
```

Comment: I use custom element as result it has no  `(onselected)`.

Comment: You don't need one! Angular allows you to put it on any element. What's your element? put it down below,. i'll show you

Comment: You did not get me. I use Anualar custom elements (web compnoents). And I use the built applicationi as web component

Comment: When is your custom component getting mounted? are you emitting from the custom element or from angular component?